# Jquery click element with key-value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do I click a radio button based on data-code value?

```
<input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="freeshipping_freeshipping" id="s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping" class="radio" data-code="Free">

<input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="freeshipping_freeshipping" id="s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping" class="radio" data-code="Sale">
```

Comment: [1](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), [2](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: Do you want to trigger click, or bind an event on click?

Answer (score 2):

That should do the trick :)

```js
$('input:radio[data-code="Sale"]').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="freeshipping_freeshipping" id="s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping" class="radio" data-code="Free">

<input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="freeshipping_freeshipping" id="s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping" class="radio" data-code="Sale">
```

Comment: That's searching **every** element. Since you know what type it is, it would be better to specify. `$('input:radio[data-code="Sale"]')`

Comment: thats true, but since that, what he asked for (no more information or code) it  does exactly what he wanted... okay, your code is more precise... i'll edit my post :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use attribute of input to do so.

For example see below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("input[data-code = 'Free']").click(function(){
         alert("hi");
     });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bcznwbnf/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input[data-code='Sale']").click(function(){alert('clicked');});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="freeshipping_freeshipping" id="s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping" class="radio" data-code="Free">

<input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="freeshipping_freeshipping" id="s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping" class="radio" data-code="Sale">
```

Comment: This will not click the element